# Regular Expression does not match test string

Tags: python, regex, apache, fail2ban

Why does the following regex not match the following text?

Regex:

```
\[\]\s\[(:?error|\S+:\S+)\]( \[pid \d+(:\S+ \d+)?\])? \[client <HOST>(:\d{1,5})?\] ModSecurity:\s+(?:\[(?:\w+ \"[^\"]*\"|[^\]]*)\]\s*)*Access denied with code [45]\d\d
```

Test string:

```
[Sun Mar 15 22:28:19.733272 2018] [:error] [pid 11954] [client 188.191.122.27:62165] [client 188.191.122.27] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Operator GE matched 4 at TX:anomaly_score. [file ".../modsecurity.d/owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "57"] [id "949110"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 5)"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"] [hostname "63.60.128.135"] [uri "/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/index.php"] [unique_id "W0uuY3C8AA4EAA5OC7wBAAAH"]
```

This is a predefined rule from fail2ban and a random apache log entry with changed addresses.

At first, I thought that the mistake is that the client is logged twice, so I changed the client line:

```
(\[client <HOST>(:\d{1,5})?\])+
```

But that didn’t seem to work either.

Just to get things clear:

```
 Regular expressions (failregex, ignoreregex) assume that the date/time has been removed from the log line (this is just how fail2ban works internally ATM).

 If the format is like „<date...> error 1.2.3.4 is evil“ then you need to match the < at the start so regex should be similar to „^<> <HOST> is evil$„ using <HOST> where the IP/domain name appears in the log line.
```

(Taken from the fail2ban docs: https://fail2ban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html) (I wrote this as code because stackoverflow seems to have problems with displaying specific characters in quotes.)

I am more or less new to regular expressions, so thanks for any help.

Comment: The regex begins with `\[\]` but the text doesn't contain `[]`.

Comment: That is due to fail2ban. It performs two checks per line, I don’t need to check the date. I think the fail2ban datedetector removes the date from the test string.

Comment: There's no `<HOST>` in the string, either.

Comment: `<HOST>` should be `(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}`

Comment: If `fail2ban` modifies the string, you need to post the resulting string that you're trying to match, not the original string.

Comment: I don't want to read all the documentation. Update the question and show what you're actually trying to match.

Comment: I updated my question and postet a quote that should make things more clear.

Comment: It would still be better if you posted one of the actual strings you're trying to match, instead of challenging us to apply the same transformations that fail2ban does.

Comment: I don’t have other strings and I don’t want to challenge you. At least not in that way. I have to write socalled „failregexes“ that fail2ban uses. I don’t get transformed strings, that is done internally within fail2ban. Basically, I don’t have to match the date and to replace the IP with <HOST>. That’s all.

Comment: Here's what I think it should be: `[] [:error] [pid 11954] [client <HOST>] [client <HOST>] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Operator GE matched 4 at TX:anomaly_score. [file ".../modsecurity.d/owasp-modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "57"] [id "949110"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 5)"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"] [hostname "<HOST>"] [uri "/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/index.php"] [unique_id "W0uuY3C8AA4EAA5OC7wBAAAH"]`

Comment: You can try using regex101.com to debug your regexp.

Comment: Do you *really* need to match the entire thing or are you just looking for something specific? There are a lot of problems with your pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. When you added the repeating group for multiple clients, you didn't include the space that separates them in it.

```
\[\]\s\[(:?error|\S+:\S+)\]( \[pid \d+(:\S+ \d+)?\])?( \[client <HOST>(:\d{1,5})?\])+ ModSecurity:\s+(?:\[(?:\w+ \"[^\"]*\"|[^\]]*)\]\s*)*Access denied with code [45]\d\d
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ymYfar/1)